# How to fix possible Jenkins errors during repo cloning?

Tags: jenkins, git-clone, jenkins-job-dsl

When I try to clone larg repo by Jenkins I have such errors in output consol.
*I try to clone Unreal Engine repo. 4.26 branch.*

- error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
- error: 4319 bytes of body are still expected
- fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
- fatal: early EOF
- fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
- FATAL: Java heap space

Also I had the problem with connect to repo inside Jenkins Job in Git section.

I already increased `timeout for clone and fetch operations`
I alreade increased `tilmeout for checkout operation` as well

For connecting git repo I tried to write different credentials, But error `Failed to connect to repo` doesn't disappearp.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have same errors during cloning repo by Jenkins you can try do this**

Open terminal and paste it

`git config --global http.postBuffer 5000` This will increase the pastBuffer value to 500mb

You can check this by typing the command below into the terminal

PS C:\Users\your_user> `cat .\.gitconfig`

**To fix `FATAL: Java heap space` you nead**

*Only for Windows*

- Open root directory of Jenkins.
- Find the `jenkins.xml` file.
- Open it.
- find the argument like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukEr0.png)
- Modify argument `-Xmx256m` to `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: To resolve a problem with connecting git repo to your Jenkins you need create Personal Access Token in your  git*** and typing like this pattern 
`https://<access token>@github.com/your/repo.git`

In this case you don't need to use Credentials.
`Credentials = none`

Comment: after all do restart Jenkins. Just type `http://localhost:8080/restart`